# Android Layout width of 50%

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am using a relative layout to create an Android UI in XML. The layout is centered around an ImageView and TextView. I need these 2 elements to lay above and below eachother. I want to make it so that these 2 elements take up 50% of the whole width. I tried a LinearLayout with an `android:layout_weight=".5"` but I couldnt get it it center both horizontally and vertically. Here is the relative layout that I have, I want it to look like this but with the image taking up 50% of the width, with 25% of whitespace on either side. I also need to do it in XML. Any guidance is appreciated.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_imageview_logo"
        android:src="@drawable/img_main_logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:paddingBottom="12dp"
        android:onClick="imageViewGTTOnClick"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_textview_tagline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/activity_main_textview_tagline"
        android:textColor="@color/dark_blue"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/activity_main_imageview_logo"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:weightSum="4"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:baselineAligned="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/activity_main_imageview_logo"
            android:src="@drawable/img_main_logo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:paddingBottom="12dp"
            android:onClick="imageViewGTTOnClick"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/activity_main_textview_tagline"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/activity_main_textview_tagline"
            android:textColor="@color/dark_blue"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="28sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Wow that was quick. Can you explain it a tiny bit? It works I would just like to learn how!

Comment: @AustinMeyers You set your main layout to have a weight sum equal to 4 and then  you give inner one 2 as weight which is 50%. If you then center it horizontaly it will have 25% of space on each side.